# Is it possible to set a custom cell's textLabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When you use the built-in styles (subtitle, right detail, etc) for `UITableViewCell`s, you can access the text labels very easily with `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` which are properties on the `UITableViewCell`, no matter which style you choose. I used this to my advantage to implement reusable code that allows me to apply specific styles to all of my static cells. But now I want to convert them all to a custom style cell, but with this style I still will only have two labels. My question is, is it possible to manually set the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties for a custom cell? If so, I would not have to change my code, I would just have to simply set the label properties. Otherwise, I'm going to have to change all of my code to target each individual label for each individual cell which will be really messy.

For an example of what I'm doing, I have a method that accepts in a `UITableViewCell` and in that method I can enable or disable that cell, which changes the labels text colors to black or light gray as appropriate. If I can't access the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties, I'm going to need to add in if statements to compare the cell parameter to my cell outlets to know which labels I need to change.

Comment: You'll have access to `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` since I'm assuming your custom cell will be a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You sure can! Just implement the getters for the labels to redirect to your custom cell's labels.

```
- (UILabel *)textLabel {
    return self.myCustomCellTextLabel;
}

- (UILabel *)detailTextLabel {
    return self.myCustomCellDetailTextLabel;
}
```

For people using Swift:

```
var textLabel: UILabel? {
    return myCustomCellTextLabel
}

var detailTextLabel: UILabel? {
    return myCustomCellDetailTextLabel
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! I've ran into a problem though. I subclassed `UITableViewCell`, added labels to a XIB, control dragged those to the subclass and returned those labels as you said, then in the storyboard I changed the custom class of each cell to my subclass and removed the labels I had in that storyboard cell. I control dragged those storyboard cells to my table view controller and in `viewDidLoad` I tried to set the text but nothing appears. Debugger shows the title label is `nil` so `self.custCell.textLabel.text = @"a"` does not cause a to appear in the cell.

Comment: Are these static cells from a storyboard?

Comment: Yes. I decided to take a different approach and just add a third label to the cell instead of creating a completely custom cell, but nonetheless I'd like to know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: This solution doesn't work in case of autolayout. iOS adds some constraints to `textLabel`, so I spent few days to understand why my layout is broken

Answer (score 1):

In custom cell, you have to add all the views in `contentView`. That's the designed way, and using of existing `textField`, and `detailTextField` is not recommended because it may cause undefined behavior by built-in layout logic. (I haven't used them. They may work well. But I will not take the risk)

If you want to avoid patching all existing code, you can try subclass and overriding the properties to labels which created by you.

```
@interface CustomCell1 : UITableViewCell
@end
@implementation CustomCell1
{
    UILabel* _your_custom_label1;
}
- (UILabel*)textLabel
{
    return _your_custom_label1;
}
@end
```